# what the differences between Install Docker Engine from binaries VS docker installation by yum and pip

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pip, yum, rhel

we want to install docker and docker compose on our rhel machine

what are the differences between Install Docker Engine from binaries VS docker installation by yum and pip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

difference is versions, an package which comes with yum should be tested for compatibility with host OS

Comment: can we installed the docke-compose also from binaries ?

Comment: Yes, you can, literaly thats what they suggest  https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/ 
`sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.5/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Comment: ( +1 ) , great but I have problem now when I start the docker , can you please help me with - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645228/installed-the-docker-from-binaries-docker-startup

Comment: you said - difference is versions , is it means that latest version of docker in binnaris  are oldest then docker with yum installation ?

Comment: so just to be sure , any negative reasons that people not installed docker with binaries because docker that installed in binaries have Disadvantages