# installed the docker from binaries + docker startup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-machine, rhel

we installed the docker from binaries as the following ( according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/ )

```
wget https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz
--2020-05-06 20:39:22--  https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz
Resolving download.docker.com (download.docker.com)... 13.225.249.16, 13.225.249.45, 13.225.249.106, ...
Connecting to download.docker.com (download.docker.com)|13.225.249.16|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 27816900 (27M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: ‘docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz’

100%[===================================================================================================================================================>] 27,816,900  4.76MB/s   in 3.7s

2020-05-06 20:39:26 (7.11 MB/s) - ‘docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz’ saved [27816900/27816900]
```

now we tar it

```
tar xzvf docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz
docker/
docker/docker-containerd-ctr
docker/docker-proxy
docker/docker
docker/docker-containerd
docker/dockerd
docker/docker-init
docker/docker-containerd-shim
docker/docker-runc
```

the files after untar

```
# ls
docker  docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz  hsperfdata_root  stable


cd docker/

# ls
docker  docker-containerd  docker-containerd-ctr  docker-containerd-shim  dockerd  docker-init  docker-proxy  docker-runc
```

now we need to start the dockerd

but how to start it

we try    y

```
/tmp/docker/dockerd
Failed to connect to containerd. Please make sure containerd is installed in your PATH or you have specified the correct address. Got error: exec: "docker-containerd": executable file not found in $PATH
```

so where we are wrong here ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you dont want or cant install it from repositories?
Running directly binary file is not remcommended and for test purposes only.

Comment: YES because many problems of yum dependencies , and this is change from one machine to other , so its impossible to install docker with auto scripts because yum dependencies

Comment: are you running it from root user? and can you install containerd from repositories at least?

Comment: yes  I am running it from root

Comment: I dont want to installed the container from repo because many dependencies problem

Comment: ok. Then download  containerd https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/download/v1.3.3/containerd-1.3.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz and try to run it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213279/discussion-between-giga-kokaia-and-jessica).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download and run containerd from [containerd](https://containerd.io/),
start it `containerd&` and then run `dockerd &`, after that you can try it `docker run hello-world`

It is not recommended way, better install it from repository with selinux or apparmor profiles.

Comment: why this isnt recommended approach ?

Comment: Because of security issues, `selinux` will not work properly.